# Galois Theory: $ a = i\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$.

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $ α = i\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ and let $K:=\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

I have to find the minimal polynomial, the degree of the extension $K:\mathbb{Q}$ and thus prove that it is simple.

I started by saying that:

$a= i\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ thus $a^2 = (i\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})^2$ which is $a^2-1=2\sqrt{6}i$.
Squaring both sides again I got: $a^4-2a^2+25=0$. Let $f(x)=x^4-2x^2+25$. Since $f(x)$ is monic, we need to show $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. If $f(x)$ has a linear factor in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then it has a zero in $\mathbb{C}$ which divides the constant term $1$. But, we see that $f(x)$ has no linear factors in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. If $f(x)$ factors into two quadratic factors in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then it has factorisation form:

$(x^2+fx+b)(x^2+cx+d)=x^4+(f+c)x^3+(fc+b+d)x^2+(fd+bc)x+bd=x^2-2x^2+25$.

Equating coefficients we get the following:

1. $f+c=0$
2. $fc+b+d=-2$
3. $fd+bc=0$
4. $bd=1$

From the fourth one, we get $2$ cases. Either $b=d=1$ or $b=d=-1$.

$1^{st}$ case: We get the following:

$f+c=0$

$fc=-12$

For which we get that $c^2=\sqrt{12}$ which does not belong in $\mathbb{Q}$, thus it is rejected.

$2^{nd}$ Case, we have the following:

$f+c=0$

$fc=8$

from which we get:

$c^2=-8$ which is again rejected.

Thus we realized that $f(x)=x^4-2x^2+25$ is a minimal polynomial of $a$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Then i just state that its degree is $4$.

To prove that it is $\textit{simple extension}$ I say:

$\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}$ is simple since $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Is my way of thinking correct? Do I need to explain some things in more detail? Any feedback is more than welcome.

Comment: "Do I need to explain some things in more detail?" Yes, you have to show that $\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: okay! Am I correct about the degree being 4? Sorry, extra nervous. First time attempting Galois Theory and have being going over Stewart's book

Comment: yes the degree should be 4

Comment: Hint: $[K:\mathbb Q]=[K:\dots][\dots:\mathbb Q]\le2\cdot2.$

Comment: @AnneBauval your comment refers to the degree of the multiplicative, right? We have $4$ complex solutions, namely: $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}i, \sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}i, -\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}i, -\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}i$ all of which have degree $1$ thus the product of their degress has degree $4$?

Comment: I didn't mean that. I meant that the 2 (quadratic) generators of $K$ may be added to $\mathbb Q$ one after another, and this gives an upper bound for the degree $[K:\mathbb Q]$ of the extension. On the other hand, by what you have done, you already know a lower bound ;-)

Comment: @AnneBauval I thought of justifying in a different way: the elements ${\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},i,i\sqrt{6}}$ form a basis for $\mathbb{Q}$$(i\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, since isomorphic field extensions have the same degree. Does this sound right?

Comment: $i$ and $\sqrt2$ don't belong to $K$, and I can't see here any isomorphic field extensions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde in order to prove that: Say $\mathbb{Q}[i\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}]\leq\mathbb{Q}[i\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$. To show converse, we must show that $\mathbb{Q}[i\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ containts both $\sqrt{3}$ and $i\sqrt{2}$. By setting $a=i\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$ I show that $\sqrt{3}= a-i\sqrt{2}$ and $i\sqrt{2}=\frac{a^3+a-2\sqrt{3}}{8}$ both belong to $\mathbb{Q}[a]$. I feel i am in the right path but there are some issues I worry about

Comment: $\sqrt{3}= a-i\sqrt{2}$ doesn't prove that $\sqrt3$ belongs to $\mathbb{Q}(a).$  To "show the converse", just prove that $[K:\mathbb Q]\le4=[\mathbb{Q}(a)
:\mathbb Q].$